# C++ template partial specialization by a function of pointer / a function of const pointer are not different?

Tags: c++, templates, constants, function-pointers

Let's consider the following code:

```
template <typename T>
class Foo
{};

template <typename T, typename U>
class Foo<T(*)(U* const)>
{};

template <typename T, typename U>
class Foo<T(*)(U*)>
{};
```

When I try compiling it [(ideone)](https://ideone.com/DKM4mS) it fails telling me the two template specializations are identical. That's surprising since normally `U*` and `U* const` are different things (the second is a const pointer). What's wrong here?

Comment: The signatures are the same. Top-level qualifiers of function parameters are silently dropped from signatures. Perhaps you wanted `U const *`?

Comment: @n.m. They are not different: I can do `Foo<U* const>` and `Foo<U*>` specializations just fine. And actually I want both `U const *` and `U * const` (and `U const * const` as well).

Comment: The types `U*` and `U* const` are different, but `T(U*)` and `T(U* const)` are the same. You cannot overload them because they are the same signature. It isn't quite clear what utility this could possibly have. It's the same as overloading `int func(int)` and `int func(const int)`. What for?

Comment: Just to illustrate: even without templates, you cannot have both `void foo(int)` and `void foo(const int)`. This is an error: [`error: redefinition of 'void foo(int)'`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0e42ec4c58f04855)

Comment: Overloading by constness of argument does not make sense. But this has nothing to do with function overloading, does it? I want to use two different specializations for two different functions (with different names).

Comment: If you want to specialize for *functions*, pass their names, not their signatures. If you have two functions `int foo(int*)` and `int bar(int*const)`, you cannot tell one from the other by ther types alone, because the types are the same. You need to use some other way, like using their names.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When determining a function's type (colloquially known as its signature), top-level cv qualifiers are dropped.

> §8.3.5/5 ... The type of a function is determined using the following
>   rules. ... After producing the list of parameter types, any top-level
>   cv-qualifiers modifying a parameter type are deleted when forming the
>   function type. ...

There are no special rules for function pointers or template arguments that void this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write it this way:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
class Foo<T(*)(const U* )>
{};
```

Comment: You cannot name anything `const`. It's a reserved word.

Comment: This is not what I want.